# how add dll file to stimulsoft ultimate or stimulsoft .net when they don't have Referenced Assemblies option

Tags: stimulsoft

I have *stimulsoft reports ultimate 2014.3* and *stimulsoft reports .net 2015.1* .
there isn't **Referenced Assemblies** option in section **Report : Report** in none of them and I can't add any **.dll** file to my report :(

now how find or return **Referenced Assemblies** option or which version I must download that have this option ?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

finaly I found that I must call context menu for the properties panel. After then select 'Professional' from menu.

After this I saw Referenced Assemblies property :)